# Escape curly braces inside triple quotes in python

Tags: python, string, f-string

I am trying to get the curly braces around capablities printed but it doesnt work for some reasons. Please advise.

```
name = 'john'
age = '18'
country = 'us'

grant = f"""
path "{name}-{age}-{country}" {
     capabilities = [ "update", "read", "list" ] 
  }
"""
print(grant.format(name,app_name,env))
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output of your print statement?

Comment: It's not clear what the f-string should fill in, and what the `format` method should.

Comment: To include a literal `{` or `}`, just double them.

Comment: @chepner I get keyerror when i try to double them  KeyError: '\n     capabilities = '

Comment: Because the `capabilities = [ ... ]` isn't a valid replacement field. What exactly is supposed to be replaced by the values of `name`, `app_name`, and `env` when you call the `format` method?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using f-strings you don't need to use .format:

```
name = 'john'
age = '18'
country = 'us'

grant = f"""
path "{name}-{age}-{country}" {{
    capabilities = [ "update", "read", "list" ]
}}
"""
print(grant)
```

prints out

```
path "john-18-us" {
     capabilities = [ "update", "read", "list" ]
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanls a lot @JMeahl